# Convert an array to json object by javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, data-structures

I am stuck to solve this problem.
Convert an array below

```
var input = [
    'animal/mammal/dog',
    'animal/mammal/cat/tiger',
    'animal/mammal/cat/lion',
    'animal/mammal/elephant',
    'animal/reptile',
    'plant/sunflower'
]
```

to json Object

```
var expectedResult = {
 "animal": {
  "mammal": {
   "dog": true,
   "cat": {
    "tiger": true,
    "lion": true
   },
   "elephant": true
  },
  "reptile": true
 },
 "plant": {
  "sunflower": true
 }
}
```

Which data structure and algorithm can I apply for it?
Thanks

Comment: "json object"! you mean JavaScript object?! JSON is a format

Comment: I mean that object has format like json. :)

Comment: it does not, it's a plain javascript object.

Comment: you should read about iterating an string and creating an object and objects inside objects recursively, it is not as difficult as it sounds.

Answer (score 4):

You need to first `split` each element to convert to array

using `reverse` `reduce` method you can convert them to object.

And your last step is merge this objects.

`Lodash.js` merge method is an one way to merge them.

```js
var input = ['animal/mammal/dog','animal/mammal/cat/tiger','animal/mammal/cat/lion', 'animal/mammal/elephant','animal/reptile', 'plant/sunflower']
var finalbyLodash={}
input.forEach(x=>{
  const keys = x.split("/");
  const result = keys.reverse().reduce((res, key) => ({[key]: res}), true);
  finalbyLodash = _.merge({}, finalbyLodash, result);
});
console.log(finalbyLodash);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

To make the process more understandable, break the problem down into pieces.

The first step is convert each string into something we can use, converting this:

```
"animal/mammal/dog"
```

into this:

```
[ "animal", "mammal", "dog" ]
```

That's an array of property names needed to build the final object.

Two functions will accomplish this for you, `String.prototype.split()` to split the string into an array, and `Array.prototype.map()` to transform each of the array elements:

```js
let splitIntoNames = input.map(str => str.split('/'));
```

The intermediate result is this:

```js
[
  [ "animal", "mammal", "dog" ],
  [ "animal", "mammal", "cat", "tiger" ],
  [ "animal", "mammal", "cat", "lion" ],
  [ "animal", "mammal", "elephant" ],
  [ "animal", "reptile" ],
  [ "plant", "sunflower" ]
]
```

Next step is to iterate over each array, using `Array.prototype.forEach()` to add properties to the object. You could add properties to the object with a for loop, but let's do that with a recursive function `addName()`:

```js
function addName(element, list, index) {
  if (index >= list.length) {
    return;
  }
  let name = list[index];
  let isEndOfList = index === list.length - 1;

  element[name] = element[name] || (isEndOfList ? true : {});

  addName(element[name], list, index + 1);
}

let result = {};
splitIntoNames.forEach((list) => {
  addName(result, list, 0);
});
```

The result:

```js
result: {
  "animal": {
    "mammal": {
      "dog": true,
      "cat": {
        "tiger": true,
        "lion": true
      },
      "elephant": true
    },
    "reptile": true
  },
  "plant": {
    "sunflower": true
  }
}
```

```js
const input = [
  "animal/mammal/dog",
  "animal/mammal/cat/tiger",
  "animal/mammal/cat/lion",
  "animal/mammal/elephant",
  "animal/reptile",
  "plant/sunflower",
];

let splitIntoNames = input.map((str) => str.split("/"));
console.log("splitIntoNames:", JSON.stringify(splitIntoNames, null, 2));

function addName(element, list, index) {
  if (index >= list.length) {
    return;
  }
  let name = list[index];
  let isEndOfList = index === list.length - 1;

  element[name] = element[name] || (isEndOfList ? true : {});

  addName(element[name], list, index + 1);
}

let result = {};
splitIntoNames.forEach((list) => {
  addName(result, list, 0);
});
console.log("result:", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

Comment: @LeDucAnh You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help. Will you accept this answer?

Comment: Yes, it is perfect. No doubt anymore. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that will slice every element from the array by "/" than you put the results into a variable and than just mount the Json. I mean something like that below:

```
    window.onload = function() {
      var expectedResult;
      var input = [
        'animal/mammal/dog',
        'animal/mammal/cat/tiger',
        'animal/mammal/cat/lion',
        'animal/mammal/elephant',
        'animal/reptile',
        'plant/sunflower'
    ]

      input.forEach(element => {
        var data = element.split('/');

        var dog = data[2] === 'dog' ? true : false
        var tiger = data[2] === 'cat' && data[3] === 'tiger'  ? true : false
        var lion = data[2] === 'cat' && data[3] === 'lion'  ? true : false


        expectedResult = {
          data[0]: {
            data[1]: {
             "dog": dog,
             "cat": {
              "tiger": tiger,
              "lion": lion
             }
            }
          }
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, here is my try. I'm implmenting `recursive` approach:

```js
var input = ['animal/mammal/dog', 'animal/mammal/cat/tiger', 'animal/mammal/cat/lion', 'animal/mammal/elephant', 'animal/reptile', 'plant/sunflower'];

result = (buildObj = (array, Obj = {}) => {
  array.forEach((val) => {
    keys = val.split('/');
    (nestedFn = (object) => {
      outKey = keys.shift();
      object[outKey] = object[outKey] || {};
      if (keys.length == 0) object[outKey] = true;
      if (keys.length > 0) nestedFn(object[outKey]);
    })(Obj)
  })
  return Obj;
})(input);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I try with array reduce, hope it help

```js
let input = [
  "animal/mammal/dog",
  "animal/mammal/cat/tiger",
  "animal/mammal/cat/lion",
  "animal/elephant",
  "animal/reptile",
  "plant/sunflower",
];

let convertInput = (i = []) =>
  i.reduce((prev, currItem = "") => {
    let pointer = prev;
    currItem.split("/").reduce((prevPre, currPre, preIdx, arrPre) => {
      if (!pointer[currPre]) {
        pointer[currPre] = preIdx === arrPre.length - 1 ? true : {};
      }
      pointer = pointer[currPre];
    }, {});
    return prev;
  }, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertInput(input), null, 4));
```